# How to use express.Router instance for error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

According to the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use), any nodejs express middleware function can be replaced by App or Router instances:

> Since router and app implement the middleware interface, you can use
>   them as you would any other middleware function.

This is some generic error handling I use:

```
express()
    .use('/test', new TestRouter())
    .use((err, req, res, next) => {
        console.error(err.stack);
        res.status(500).send(err.message);
    })
    .listen(PORT);
```

I tried to replace my error handling with an error-handling Router, but now the callback is never executed and express uses it's default error handling.

```
const handler = new express.Router();
handler.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
});

express()
    .use('/test', new TestRouter())
    .use(handler)
    .listen(PORT);
```

Why is this not working as expected and how could I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error handlers need to be configured as the last calls to `use`, as per the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#writing-error-handlers)

> You define error-handling middleware last, after other app.use() and routes calls;

I would say "routes" also buckets Routers therefore what you are trying to do doesn't look like it's supported.

---

Just digging further into this, I believe the issue is down to the fact Routers have separate Layer stacks. Express behind the scenes is effectively just a `Router` (we see [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3ed5090ca91f6a387e66370d57ead94d886275e1/lib/application.js#L214) where this is setup, and then further down where the middleware is [delegated](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3ed5090ca91f6a387e66370d57ead94d886275e1/lib/application.js#L228) on to the Router). Internally, middleware functions are represented as "Layers" (as seen [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/f3fa758af9664526ee18c58764590e48f559e6ae/lib/router/index.js#L464)) and looking at the [constructor](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/f3fa758af9664526ee18c58764590e48f559e6ae/lib/router/index.js#L58), we can see Routers have their own stack.

So consider the following example:

```
express()
  .use(new RouterA())
  .use(new RouterB())
  .use((err, req, res, next) => {
    ...
  })
  .listen(PORT);
```

Which, by looking at the source, can be viewed as:

```
express()
  .use((req, res, next) => {
    router.handle(req, res, next);
  })
  .use((req, res, next) => {
    router.handle(req, res, next);
  })
  .use((err, req, res, next) => {
    ...
  });
```

Therefore, if an error is thrown in `RouterA`, the Router would firstly check its own middleware stack for a matching error Layer (i.e. a `(err, req, res, next)` function) and execute that, it would then bubble up to the app level and perform the same action.

So given your example, if you consider the translated code, this explains why it won't catch your error handler in the second Router - a Router signature does not match that of an error handler therefore it would be skipped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I get you right, it will not work, since the last call is not the error handling callback itself. Instead, I am using my app's last call, to run through a router... right?

Comment: @Basti correct, I think this is down to the fact that Routers have their own separate layer stack. For example, I presume you are testing this by throwing an error inside `TestRouter` and expecting it to be handled by `handler`? Try putting an error handler in the same router you are throwing and let me know if it catches.

Comment: Hi there, I played around and tried different things and meanwhile I don't think it is important to chain the handler at the end (I was able to place multiple handlers everywhere). Instead, I think the difference is, that routers and express-app instances are registered with 3 arguments, so they are not considered to be error handlers and so they are just skipped during error handling. See my post for some references.

Comment: @Basti I'm not really seeing anything you've mentioned here that isn't already explained by my answer? When I refer to an "error handler" I am referring to a function with the params `err, req, res, next` as demonstrated in the examples. I thought that was a bit of a given considering if it wasn't then _any_ route declared after an error occurred would be processed (which of course wouldn't make any sense).

Comment: For me, these are two different answers. Please don't get me wrong, I am very grateful for your answer and clarification and I feel bad for arguing here! I am totally new to express, but in my eyes, the root cause for my problem is, that you can't register a Router as an error handler because it takes 3 arguments. You probably knew it and implied it, but it's not part of your answer, so I didn't know.

Comment: Sorry, after reading your answer again with some more experience, I totally see your point, we were talking about the same thing from different perspectives. I just didn't understand the implied knowledge about the 4 arguments for error handlers. May you add one ore two sentences about it and I will accept your answer?

Comment: @Basti as I commented on your answer, I took for granted that you were already aware of the fact an error handler takes 4 arguments (primarily because you had already explained you had one configured). I could expand the final sentence just to explain that it doesn't catch *because* the function signature of a Router doesn't match that of an error handler, as you say it's implied but I can make that more explicit for anyone not familiar with Express.

Comment: Yes, sounds great, thank you and thanks for your effort and patience!